# Add a label to map at each leg start

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm plotting legs of a route to a ggmap.  It works okay so far.  I've been trying to add a label containing the order (n from the loop) of each leg.

I've tried +geom_text to the geom_leg() but I get the error :

```
Error in geom_leg(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat, xend = endLon, yend = endLat),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'd appreciate any help adding a label to indicate the leg.

Data :

```
structure(c("53.193418", "53.1905138631287", "53.186744", "53.189836", 
"53.1884117", "53.1902965", "53.1940384", "53.1934748", "53.1894004", 
"53.1916771", "-2.881248", "-2.89043889005541", "-2.890165", 
"-2.893896", "-2.88802", "-2.8919373", "-2.8972299", "-2.8814698", 
"-2.8886692", "-2.8846099"), .Dim = c(10L, 2L))
```

Function :

```
create.map<-function(lst){

library("ggmap")


cncat<-c(paste(lst[,1],lst[,2],sep=","))

df2<-data.frame(cncat)

leg <-function(start, dest, order){

  r<- route(from=start,to=dest,mode = c("walking"),structure = c("legs"))  
  c<- geom_leg(aes(x = startLon, y = startLat,xend = endLon, yend = endLat),
               alpha = 2/4, size = 2, data = r,colour = 'blue')+
    geom_text(aes(label = order), size = 3)

  return (c)
}

a<-qmap('Chester, UK', zoom = 15, maptype = 'road')  

for (n in 1:9){
  l<-leg(as.character(df2[n,1]), as.character(df2[n+1,1]),n)  
  a<-a+l
}

a

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this close? (Note: this calls your list of points `way.points`).

[image]

```
way.points <- as.data.frame(way.points,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
library(ggmap)
rte.from <- apply(way.points[-nrow(way.points),],1,paste,collapse=",")
rte.to   <- apply(way.points[-1,],1,paste,collapse=",")
rte      <- do.call(rbind,
                    mapply(route, rte.from, rte.to, SIMPLIFY=FALSE,
                           MoreArgs=list(mode="walking",structure="legs")))
coords   <- rbind(as.matrix(rte[,7:8]),as.matrix(rte[nrow(rte),9:10]))
coords   <- as.data.frame(coords)
ggm <- qmap('Chester, UK', zoom = 15, maptype = 'road')  
ggm +
  geom_path(data=coords,aes(x=startLon,y=startLat),color="blue",size=2)+
  geom_point(data=way.points,aes(x=as.numeric(V2),y=as.numeric(V1)),
             size=10,color="yellow")+
  geom_text(data=way.points,
            aes(x=as.numeric(V2),y=as.numeric(V1), label=seq_along(V1)))
```

So this assembles a vector of from and to coordinates using `apply(...)`, then uses `mapply(...)` to call `route(...)` with both vectors, returning the overall list of coordinates in a data frame `rte`. Because the coordinates are stored as, e.g. `$startLat` and `$endLat`, we form a `coords` data frame by adding the final `$endLat` and `$endLong` to `rte` to get the very last leg of the route. Then we use `geom_path(...)` to draw the path in one step. Finally we use `geom_text(...)` with x and y-values from the original `way.points` data frame, and we use `geom_point(...)` just to make them stand out a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bare bones solution. I just added the labels to the finished ggmap object `a`. If you replace the line

```
 a
```

with

```
lst2 <- data.frame(cbind(lst, leg = as.character(1:10) )
names(lst2) <- c("lat", "lon", "leg")
a <- a + geom_text(data=lst2,aes(x=lon,y=lat,label=leg),size=5, vjust = 0, hjust = -0.5)
return(a)
```

in your `create.map` function, you should get (roughly) the desired result.  I might have reversed the `lat` and `lon` variables, and you probably want to tweak the size, location, etc. Hope this helps!